# No “The overflow” option on Email settings for full web version

Tags: bug, mobile-web, email

Why does the full web version of the [Email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) page not contain “The overflow” section that the mobile web version does? See the images below:

- mobile web

> [image]

- full site

> [image]